# Does Heroku Neo4j addon support streaming REST api?

Tags: rest, heroku, streaming, neo4j

Does anyone know if [Heroku Neo4j addon](https://addons.heroku.com/neo4j) supports [streaming REST api](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-streaming.html)?

As per [this](http://jexp.de/blog/2012/04/on-streaming-cypher/) article, enabling streaming api requires streaming-cypher-extension jar to be added to the Neo4j server. Does Heroku Neo4j addon server has that?

(I could not find anywhere in the Heroku Neo4j addon documentation whether it supports streaming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heroku REST API uses the same code, so I think it is supported.